# How to update URL in redux simple router from action?

Tags: redux, react-router-redux

According to the redux simple router docs, you can update the route from an action. I don't see how to do that in the documentation. Does anyone have an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the [history](https://github.com/mjackson/history) singleton passed to your root component into the action and operate on it directly, or, if you've installed the router middleware, you can use the action creators provided by `react-router-redux`.

From the [docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#what-if-i-want-to-issue-navigation-events-via-redux-actions):

> #### What if I want to issue navigation events via Redux actions?
>
> React Router provides singleton versions of history (browserHistory
>   and hashHistory) that you can import and use from anywhere in your
>   application. However, if you prefer Redux style actions, the library
>   also provides a set of action creators and a middleware to capture
>   them and redirect them to your history instance.
>
> ```
> import { routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'
>
> // Apply the middleware to the store
> const middleware = routerMiddleware(browserHistory)
> const store = createStore(
>   reducers,
>   applyMiddleware(middleware)
> )
>
> // Dispatch from anywhere like normal.
> store.dispatch(push('/foo'))
> ```

The following [actions are supported](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#pushlocation-replacelocation-gonumber-goback-goforward):

`push(location)`
`replace(location)`
`go(number)`
`goBack()`
`goForward()`